# Why does Preview remain active in the background?

Tags: macos, mac, preview, force-quit

I have noticed quite a few times that after viewing a particular image and quitting Preview manually, Preview still remains active in the background sucking up huge chunks memory/RAM. It only stops after force quitting it. I don't know why this does happen!

Comment: How did you close it? Did you use File > Quit (⌘Q), or did you just close the window?

Comment: Right Click and Quit then Force Quit

Comment: So, you try to quit it, and it then locks up without quitting? Do you get the spinning beach ball of doom?

Comment: @seaturtle And it still remains active in the background!

Comment: See after I have successfully opened an image with preview I close preview by right>quit (Mouse) then I go to activity monitor and I see that preview is still active in the background so until and unless I press Command-Option-Escape and force quit it, it doesn't quits and I don't get the beach ball of doom!

Comment: That's very odd. If you go into the terminal and type this command `ps -xc | grep Preview` both before and after quitting, what do you get? (I'm thinking maybe something is relaunching it after it quits. It's unlikely, but...)

Comment: @seaturtle Before: 6130 ??         0:06.11 Preview
 6131 ??         0:00.02 com.apple.Preview.TrustedBookmarksService After: 6130 ??         0:06.11 Preview
 6131 ??         0:00.02 com.apple.Preview.TrustedBookmarksService

Comment: OK. That tells me that it's staying open, not quitting and relaunching. (That first number is a [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier), which changes when the app is quit and relaunched.) What happens if you include `j` in the flags, like this? `ps -xcj | grep Preview`

Comment: Also, if you want to see what all that output means, replace `| grep Preview` with `| head -n 1` to see the column headers instead.

Comment: This is what I get after force quitting preview: sayan  6172     1  6172      0    1 S      ??    0:01.27 Preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66112/discussion-between-seaturtle-and-sayan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens a lot. Preview is supposed to auto-terminate – but often cannot. 
As of this writing: this is a bug not fixed in Sierra and not fixed in High Sierra.
Even force quitting the app from the Dock might surprise you: after one trigger-the-bug files hangs Preview, force quit the app from the Dock and open Activity Monitor. Even though the app has lost its indicator light in the Dock and will not show up if you switch through your applications with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> it may very well be still shown as running– and sometimes with quite a hefty CPU toll. Since this is a bug in all versions of Preview that are supposed to be able to be auto-terminated, you have not many options:

- disable auto-termination to mitigate some of these effects and get a bit more manual control over the situation with `defaults write -g NSDisableAutomaticTermination -bool yes`
- if it happens: force-quit the app(-process) with Activity Monitor
- or do it from Terminal: `sudo killall Preview`

Best option of course is not to use the buggy program and choose an alternative picture and PDF viewer.

Comment: If I use the first option what are the changes I will encounter and the will the changes be for each and every app which are not needed to get this change?

Comment: Only apps that *should* auto-erminate will be affected. The observed behaviour should be like in older systems: only when *you* quit an app will it go. Try it out. If that does not suit you reverse it with `defaults delete -g NSDisableAutomaticTermination`

Comment: I tried the first solution and fortunately It worked!

Comment: Can you recommend some good alternatives?

Comment: Full spec PDF compatibility? Adobe Reader. https://pdfexpert.com, maybe foxit https://www.foxitsoftware.com

Comment: Will it be light on the system just like Preview?

Comment: Not the slow Adobe. Foxit maybe, PDFExpert is great.

Comment: I would argue force quitting is part of the problem rather than letting preview wrap up work and exit cleanly. Does anyone have a radar or bug number for this actual bug? I’d be interested in filing a duplicate if someone has a test file that triggers this bug after a restart.

Answer (score 2):

This is by design and expected behavior if your memory pressure is green in activity monitor. Both iOS and macOS will keep some apps resident until compressed memory or paging is called for and then purge them. Changes in the kernel relating to App Nap, sudden termination, background processing [allow many more states for applications than just running and quit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsprocessinfo#main).

Why do you care whether the process is still in memory?  It's not *running*.  Preview.app supports Automatic Termination, the system will remove it from memory when it is necessary to to so.

Comment: That is where the problem is, it is not terminating by it-self and thus sucking up upto 20% of my CPU and RAM

Comment: @Sayan I’ve added some context and a developer link on the many states that processes now can inhabit. What is the memory pressure when you feel the app should be terminated? Can you reproduce that after a clean restart?